# ASP.NET wildcard in *.browsers file

Tags: asp.net, user-agent, infragistics

I have a website with broken legacy 3rd party controls that is incorrectly parsing anything with a double digit version number.

See the utterly silly bug report here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/65047.aspx

e.g. Firefox 9.0 is fine. Firefox 10.0 breaks.

I can't change the source of the controls and I just need to get this fixed for a client - I don't care how.

I am currently attempting to override the *.browser file with a wildcard that will let me force the version number to something else ***NO MATTER WHAT THE BROWSER ACTUALLY IS***.

How can I get this done? Here's what I've tried so far...

```
<browser id="Wildcard" parentID="Default">
  <identification>
      <userAgent match="." />
  </identification>
  <capabilities>
      <capability name="majorversion" value="9" />
      <capability name="minorversion" value="0" />
      <capability name="version" value="9.0" />
  </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to *extend* the `Default` definition with `refID` instead of wildcarding the user-agent or some such hack. The final result is as simple as this:

```
<browser refID="Default">
    <capabilities>
        <capability name="majorversion" value="9" />
        <capability name="minorversion" value="0" />
        <capability name="version" value="9.0" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```